# Get reference to Views in my Android Activity

Tags: android, button, view, iterator

I have a `LinearLayout` comprising of a few `Button`s and I add this to my activity in the `onCreate(..)` method with `setContentView(R.layout.myscreen)`. No surprises so far.

How do I get a reference to an iterator to these buttons? I'd like to add listeners to them but I'd rather not directly reference the Button's using their `android:id`.

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872238/enumerate-iterate-all-views-in-activity) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221135/how-to-get-every-views-in-an-activity) but they don't quite answer my question.

Comment: Is every `Button` going to have the same listener?

Comment: At the moment I was going to just create a new listener for each button but I'm open to suggestions. I just want to add an onClickListener to get the text in the button to do something with it. Is there a simpler way to just add a generic listener to the entire View?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this provide an id root_layout in xml to LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
    for(int i = 0; i < mLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        Button mButton = (Button) mLayout.getChildAt(i);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Where mLayout is object of you Linear Layout and Your activity must implements `OnClickListener` and here goes general listener

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Button mButton = (Button)v;
    String buttonText = mButton.getText().toString();

}
```

**NOTE:** For this to work properly you Linear Layout must only contains button no other views

Comment: Thank you Tox1c. I hate asking this question but how do you access the Layout from an Activity? This is one of the things that I hate in Android - I **know** something is in there somewhere to do something  but because the API is so vast I just can't find it. There is a `setContentView(..)` method but no `getContentView(..)`

Comment: If I pretend to keep a reference to the view for the whole life of the activity, should I use a weakreference or nah

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-does-exactly-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistener/4153842#4153842).

In short. I'd assign the buttons a listener by setting the `onClick` attribute in the XML layout on each `Button`.

Inside of your `Activity` you'll need a public method like the one below which basically is what you want to do in your listener.

```
public void myFancyMethod(View v) {
    // do something interesting here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Octavian. Didn't know about that XML setting.However in attempting to keep the initial question short and clear I left out the fact that I also want to attach an `onLongClickListener` and `OnFocusChangeListener` to the buttons so I still need to get a reference to the buttons. As a last resort I can just directly reference the Buttons using their `android:id` but it's a little inflexible. Any ideas? cheers

Comment: btw octavian.. I've tried to also vote your answer up as it is useful also but its not letting me as I was messing around. Can you just edit it slightly (add whitespace) so I can re-vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for accessing other elements you may try following syntax:

`<ElementClass> <referencevariable> = (<ElementClass>) findViewById(R.id.<id_of_the_element>);`

For Example:

`TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1); //I used t1 to refer my textview in the Layout.`

This might work.
Then you can use these views with their inbuilt methods to perform as many as work you want.

Comment: I used following code:

`textView.setText(message);`

worked in my case... may come to your help.