# How to Scroll to some particular textview element using soothscroll?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-spinner

In my page I have two parts. One is drop down which contains multiple categories. And other one contains products of all categories. Like I showed in image. When user Clicking any category then the page get scroll to the appropriate products of choosed category.

**Up to now I have tried**:-
First of all, I need to bind dynamically Category names in the spinner. After that I need to bind the products with the Category name having the id of spinner's value. So, when user choosing anything I need to get the value from the spinner and after that I need to match that value with the products elements. Once it get matched then my page should scroll to that particular element. For this anybody having any idea?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6UeX.jpg)

Comment: please clarify your question, you're getting down-votes because it's hard to understand what you're asking

Comment: Check my updated Query... @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 0):

You can check your view visibility:

```java
if (youtTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
     //Your TextView is visible
} else {
     //Your TextView is not visible (invisible or gone)
}
```

Comment: Here, When user choose an item in spinner, then I am just taking that value from the spinner and after that I need to check that is there any text view is present in the same name of choosed value of the spinner. For this Could you help me?@Evyatar Cohen

Comment: Do you mean that the TextView have the same value like the spinner?

Like, if the user choose from the spiner "my string" then you need to find if a string with the value "my string" is visible?

Comment: Yes.. you are right... for ex: if user choose a value like "Brain" then i need to find the text view which having the id as same as he choosed like "Brain".

Comment: So maybe you can use loop to find which TextView is equal to the string from your spinner. and then check for the visibility of the specific TextView

Comment: yes.. for that only i don't know how to put my textview in loop for checking?

Comment: Hope this will help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221135/how-to-get-all-views-in-an-activity

Answer (score 0):

A TextView needs an id to be assigned in your XML layout.

> android:id="+id/SomeName"

Now in your main java class, you need to declare a TextView type variable.

```
private TextView textView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.SomeName);
```

Now while typing the lastline if you see R.id."SomeName" appearing in the template of android studio , then that means your textview is present in the current layout which you have defined in the setContentView(....);

If its not present it will throw a redline or null error.
As for Visibility, you can use the `.getVisibility()` function.

**UPDATED ANSWER **

```
  View parent = layout.getParent();
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof TextView)
        {
              String spinner= mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
              String tv= v.getText().toString();
              if (str1.equals(str2)) {
            // Show code you want
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here, When user choose an item in spinner, then I am just taking that value from the spinner and after that I need to check that is there any text view is present in the same name of choosed value of the spinner. For this Could you help me? @Sourish Mukherjee

Comment: You mean TextView with the same id name  or TextView with the same text or content name?

Comment: Let me give me a second to explain briefly... Spinner and text views available in the app page are having same value and ids. Like Spinner Value = Text View id...@Sourish Mukherjee

Comment: make sure your parent layout has child views. Also check the error being shown in the android studio.

Comment: May I know why you are not using ListView or Recycler View

Comment: What you can do is use a ListView. Set all of your categories in ListView by using a Custom Adapter Class. You can use the function .smoothScrollToPosition(int position);

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check text in **TextView** and **Spinner**, right? My suggestions:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String str1 = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String str2 = textview.getText().toString();
            if (str1.equals(str2)) {
                // Show code you want
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your code... but in your code at line no 5, textview means which one? @DinhNguyen

Comment: **textview** is your Text View's id you want to check

Comment: but here you didn't check the textview is present or not using the spinner value?

Comment: if the textview don't have any text, so **str2** = "" (empty string).

Comment: here i need to check whether any text view having same id of spinner value which is user choosed

Comment: in your code `
            String str1 = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String str2 = textview.getText().toString();
            if (str1.equals(str2)) {
                // Show code you want
            }
        }`..... you are taking the choosed value form the spinner and converting to string after that you stored it in `str1`. But in my case after this i need to check any text views are available or not with the same id of he choosed..

Comment: I see, so you need to create a list of the textview you want to check, and use **for()** method to check if any textview equal selected item of spinner

Comment: By the OP 's comment in another answers