# Get specific type of view from parent view

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, rootview

Do you guys know if there's a proper manner to get all specific view types from the parent view as the title says?

I would like to get all the EditText views from my activity, so I wonder if there's a better way than using this solution [get all views from an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221135/how-to-get-all-views-in-an-activity) and then testing every view to check if it's an EditText or not?

Thank you for the help,

Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1 :

Let's say you named your edittext edittext_0, edittext_1, .. edittext_n. You can do:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int id = vg.getResources().getIdentifier("edittext_"+i, "id", getPackageName());
     edittext[i] = (EditText) vg.findViewById(id);
}
```

Actually the answers specified in the link given, are feasible if you have a large number of views, but if you want a specific type of view from a view/viewgroup, simply use findViewById method.
Example :

```
(in Kotlin) //Similar syntax in java
val view : View = findViewById(your_layout_or_any_other_view)
val childView : EditText = view.findViewById(edittext_id)
```

*OPTIONAL READING*

Optimised Answer for the answers given in link :

It is easier with Kotlin using for-in loop:

```
for (childView in ll.children) {
     if(childView.id == your_edittext_id) //If required
     //childView is a child of ll         
}
//Here ll is id of LinearLayout defined in layout XML.
```

Comment: Thank you man, btw i can't upvote as i'm new here ;(

Comment: Glad it helped. Anyway, I think anyone can upvote helpful answers.